# Azure Pipelines - Share mount for caching between pipelines?

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hia!

Currently we're configuring Azure Pipelines for building or applications, libraries and what have you. Right now, things spins locally with a Jenkins setup running Jenkins Pipelines. This works all well and good. Migrating to use Azure Pipelines instead; and things still works all fine and we can perform builds, deploy artifacts/applications to k8s, azure artifacts etc. As mentioned; All well and good!

However, the libraries and applications that we're working with are Maven/Gradle based. Right now, we've set up a "Caching task" per pipeline to speed things up - as the documentation tells us. However, as we have quite a few applications (200+) running with Pipelines, things starts to get quite big in terms of caching per application and mb stored (which cost $$$$).

With our nice "On-Prem" Jenkins-solution, everything (all libraries and applications) uses a defined `.m2`-folder, where libraries (dependencies) required by our projects reside.

Is there any way to mimic this functionality with Azure Pipelines?

E.g, idk, mounting a disk via Blob Store, copying files from a common share or something similar like that?

We've tried a few things, but can't seem to land on something :-). Hope someone have some ideas as it should be a fairly common issue. Tried googling but the internet says no.

Regards,
`>.>`

Comment: Which kind of agent do you use? It seems like you're looking for self-hosted(on-premise) agents. Feel free to correct me if I misunderstand anything:)

Comment: Basically, within these 200 pipelines that we have, I would like to not use a separate caching per job - I'd like to just use a separate solution for that - be it blob store or whatnot, doesn't matter - the point is that we don't want to store the exactly same dependencies all over the place in each of the pipelines, as the pipelines is separate by nature and thus caching cannot be shared between them :)

Comment: If you're using [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops), since every instance will be released after executaion, they're separate. You may consider using [self-agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops), then all your pipeline can use same cache in that agent.